# Ifstream read strange behavior

Tags: c++, file, ifstream

I'm using C++ to read some chars from a file and store them in a buffer, however, I'm witnessing strange behavior with `ifstream`'s read function.

To start with, I'm using this code snippet to get the file's length:

```
input.seekg (0, input.end);
int length = input.tellg();
input.seekg (0, input.beg);
```

After that, I call **read()** to get **length** bytes from the file.

It works fine, except for one thing:
If I use **input.gcount()** to see how many bytes were read, this number is much less that the length of the file we got above (but shows the *actual* nuber of bytes in the file).

Do you guys know anything about the difference between the file's length, found by using **tellg()**, and the number of bytes read afterwards, as reported by **gcount()**?

Sorry for any formatting issues (I'm using my phone).

Thanks a lot.

Edit :

That's the code (more or less) I'm using:

```
ifstream input("test.txt");

input.seekg (0, input.end);
int length = input.tellg();
input.seekg (0, input.beg);

input.read(buffer,length);

int extracted = input.gcount();
```

Comment: `tellg()` returns the position in the external sequence while `gcount()` returns the number of characters read from the most recent unformatted input function. It follows that unless you read the total number of characters from the external sequence, `gcount()` will invariably return a smaller value than the total number of characters.

Comment: Thanks for your comment... Yes, I forgot to mention that, I *am* reading the whole file with read()... Shouldn't the number returned by tellg() be the same as gcount()?

Comment: Then please show the code.

Comment: Can you add the `ifstream` instantiation code? Perhaps you are trying to read a binary file without using `std::ios::binary`, this a common source of failure.

Comment: Ahh well, as I mentioned I currently can't show the entire source , as I'm using my phone... I can edit the relevant code however.

Comment: I'm trying to read a txt file like this : ifstream input ("test.txt");

Comment: @AleksanderBavdaz That's most likely the issue here.

Comment: Can a txt file be a binary file?!

Comment: Extracted is different than length in the code above

Comment: Yes, a `.txt` file can contain anything, depending on what you wrote into it. The extension is no guarantee for the files contents.

Comment: What I really meant by .txt (wasn't really obvious), is a normal text file. In my case it contains just integers written in notepad...

Answer (score 2):

[Fstream's tellg / seekg returning higher value than expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641639/fstreams-tellg-seekg-returning-higher-value-than-expected)

Just found this link... It explains it nicely!

Turns out I need to search a little bit more before posting...

Thank you all for your answers