# strlen not counting newlines?

Tags: visual-c++, lua, visual-studio-2015

I embedded lua into my project and came across a strange (for me) behavior of `strlen` and lua interpreting. I was trying to load a string, containing lua code, with `luaL_loadbuffer` and it consistently threw error of "`unexpected symbol`" on whatever was the last line of the lua code, except if the whole chunk was written in one line. so for example:

```
  function start()
      print("start")
  end
```

would always results error: unexpected symbol on 3rd line, but

```
function start() print("start") end
```

loads successfully.

I figured out that loading the same chunk with `luaL_loadstring`, gives no errors, and saw that it uses `strlen` to determine the length of the specified string (I used `std::string::size`) and also that using strlen to provide the length of the string to the `luaL_loadbuffer` also results in successful loading.

Now the question was: what may be the difference between strlen and std::string::size, and at my most surprise the answer is that strlen is not counting new lines ('`\n`'). That is:

```
 const char* str  = "this is a string\nthis is a newline";
  std::string str2(str);
  str2.size(); // gives 34
  strlen(str); // gives 33
```

The difference between the size, and the value returned by strlen was always the number of new line characters.

My questions are:

1. Does strlen really not counting newlines or I am missing something?
2. How do newlines affect the interpretation of the lua code internally?

I am using vs 2015 and lua 5.3.0

**EDIT:**

My first example was not exact, and did not produce the detailed effect for me neither, but I was able to recreate the problem from the original code:

```
std::fstream _Stream("test.lua", std::ios::ate | std::ios::in);
    std::string _Source;
    if(_Stream.is_open()) {
        _Source.resize(_Stream.tellg());
        _Stream.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        _Stream.read(&_Source[0], _Source.size());
        _Stream.close();
    }

    std::cout << "std::string::size() = " << _Source.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "strlen() = " << strlen(_Source.c_str()) << std::endl;
```

The content of test.lua is `"function start()\n\tprint("start")\nend\n\nstart()"`

The difference is the number of newlines:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0QOW.png

Comment: i believe that strlen dont give you the final character (the hidden \0), and the size function is called after the string constructor is called (i.e the final character is included in str2, but not in the lenght gave by strlen function)

Comment: `cout << strlen(str) << endl;` gevies 34 for me.

Comment: so what?? so what about str2.size(); // gives 34
  strlen(str); // gives 33

Comment: why you say that cout << strlen(str) << endl; gives 34 in a place and in another place you say 33?

Comment: You are mistaken - both expressions [evaluate to 34](http://rextester.com/JMOJB66242)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik my example was not exact, please see edited version

Comment: Add std::ios::binary, and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window's line endings (CR+LF) are two characters making the file size larger than the number of characters in the string so the `resize` operation  uses the file size and not the length of the null-terminated string. `strlen` reports the length of the null-terminated string and counts `\n` as a single character. You can make the size match the length of the C string by resizing the string to match afterwards:

```
_Source.resize(strlen(_Source.c_str()) + 1);
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641639/fstreams-tellg-seekg-returning-higher-value-than-expected

Comment: Thanks, saving the file with unix line-endings shows the difference.